# Why is my AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException not being respected?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a spring boot service method as shown below. This receives a rabbit message and does some things. The problem is its attempting to consume the same message over and over again even if it throws an exception.

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = {"#{ rabbitConfig.responseQueue }"})
    public void receive(final Message<String> message) {
        try {
                //blah blah 
                .....
                case ERROR:
                    handleJobError(((EngineServiceErrorDto) responseDto).error, messageHeaders);
                    throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Error");
             }
    catch (final JsonProcessingException jsonProcessingException) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(
                    String.format(JSON_PROCESSING_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, message.getHeaders()), jsonProcessingException);
        }
```

This is my rabbit config:

```
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          initial-interval: 3s
          max-attempts: 6
          max-interval: 10s
          multiplier: 2
        default-requeue-rejected: false
```

Notice how I have set the default-requeue-rejected to false which is supposed to stop picking up messages which have already failed. ??

What I want to happen is that if I receive an ERROR message, I want to throw an exception in my application and stop trying to re-receive the message. How can I do this ?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense; both situations (the property and exception) will cause the message to be rejected and not re-queued, so something is wrong. Turn on DEBUG logging, and look for `logger.debug("Rejecting messages (requeue=" + shouldRequeue + ")");`. If you can't figure it out, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace so we can see what's wrong.